# fetch().then() return content-type and body

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

Every fetch API example on the internet shows how to return only the body using response.json(), response.blob() etc.
What I need is to call a function with both the content-type and the body as a blob and I cannot figure out how to do it.

```
fetch("url to an image of unknown type")
  .then((response) => {
    return {
      contentType: response.headers.get("Content-Type"),
      raw: response.blob()
  })
  .then((data) => {
    imageHandler(data.contentType, data.raw);
  });
```

This obviously doesn't work: data.contentType is filled, but data.raw is a promise. How can I get both values in the same context?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could write it that way:

```
fetch("url to an image of unknown type")
  .then(response => {
    return response.blob().then(blob => {
      return {
        contentType: response.headers.get("Content-Type"),
        raw: blob
      }
    })
  })
  .then(data => {
    imageHandler(data.contentType, data.raw);
  });
```

Or this way

```
fetch("url to an image of unknown type")
  .then(response => {
    return response.blob().then(blob => {
        imageHandler(response.headers.get("Content-Type"), blob)
    })
  })
```

In both cases you keep the callback in which you receive the resolved `blob` within the scope where you have access to `response`.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think about doing a then() call inside another then(). And +1 for giving two examples.

Answer (score 6):

If you are allowed to use `async` functions the best solution is to use `async/await`

```js
async function fetchData() {
    const res = await fetch('url');
    const contentType = res.headers.get('Content-Type');
    const raw = await res.blob();
    // you have raw data and content-type

    imageHandler(contentType, raw);
}
```

If not:

```js
fetch('')
    .then((res) => res.blob().then((raw) => {
        return { contentType: res.headers.get('Content-Type'), raw };
    }))
    .then((data) => {
        imageHandler(data.contentType, data.raw);
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Wait for the blob then create the object :

```
fetch("url to an image of unknown type")
.then(response => {
  return response.blob()
  .then(raw => ({
    contentType: response.headers.get("Content-Type"),
    raw
  }));
).then(data => imageHandler(
  data.contentType,
  data.raw
));
```