# How to get data and response status from API using node-fetch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-fetch

As per the node-fetch documentation [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)

we can get the response status like this

```
fetch('https://github.com/')
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res.status);
    });
```

and for getting the data

```
fetch('https://api.github.com/users/github')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(jsonData => console.log(jsonData));
```

I have a scenario where I need to return the JSON data and the status from the response. I tried to use like this

```
     fetch('https://api.github.com/users/github')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(jsonData => {
             console.log(jsonData);
             console.log(jsonData.status);
      });
```

but the

> console.log(jsonData.status)

won't return the status. How I can get status and output data

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51972767/2767755). It has the hint how to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access previous promise results in a .then() chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250680/how-do-i-access-previous-promise-results-in-a-then-chain)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to declare a variable and assign `res.status` value to it:

```
let status; 
fetch('https://api.github.com/users/github')
  .then((res) => { 
    status = res.status; 
    return res.json() 
  })
  .then((jsonResponse) => {
    console.log(jsonResponse);
    console.log(status);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // handle error
    console.error(err);
  });
```

You can also try it that way using `async/await`:

```
const retrieveResponseStatus = async (url) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const { status } = response; 
    return status;
  } catch (err) {
   // handle error
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

Then You can use it with any URL You want:

`const status = await retrieveStatus('https://api.github.com/users/github')`

Answer (score 14):

Another alternative solution is using `Promise.all`

```
fetch('https://api.github.com/users/github')
  .then(res => Promise.all([res.status, res.json()]))
  .then(([status, jsonData]) => {
    console.log(jsonData);
    console.log(status);
  });
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I find this solution the most elegant by far, thanks!

Comment: This solution makes the most sense.

Answer (score -1):

I might be going in opposite direction however I would suggest you to use [requestJs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request), as its community is much bigger then node-fetch and provides lots of functionality.

With requestJs you can fetch statusCode like

```
 request("https://api.github.com/users/github", (err, res, body) => {
     let statusCode = res.statusCode;
 });
```

RequestJs also provides lots of easy way to call different API methods and also easy to watch API request and API response.

Comment: Request has been deprecated

Answer (score -1):

Here is yet another variant, using async lambda functions and array destructuring:

```
fetch('https://api.github.com/users/github')
  .then(async (res) => {  
    return [await res.json(), res.status];
  })
  .then(([jsonData, status]) => {
    console.log(jsonData);
    console.log(status);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // handle error
    console.error(err);
  });
```